# Drupal 7: Transferring New Theme from Testing Server to Live Server

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

My goal is to re-design my Drupal 7 site using a new theme (Adaptivetheme). I copied my database and all Drupal files over to a testing server. No big deal.

Now the problem is: When I am finished customizing the new theme, how do I put that onto the live site? I can't put the testing database onto the live site because there are obviously new data in the days, weeks, etc. since I did the initial copy of the real database. Or put another way: is there any way to transfer ONLY the newly-added posts, etc., from the live site to the testing site without overriding the newly-created theme?

Comment: You can just deploy the code without the database. You will keep all your production data.

Answer (score 1):

When you finish your new theme copy all it's files in `/sites/all/themes/theme_name`. Your current theme should be there, in `/sites/all/themes` too. Then in back-end go to "Appearance" and activate your new theme. Clear the cache if you have to. If everything is ok...leave it like that.

If you are not satisfied with new theme just go again to "Appearence" and activate your old theme...until new one is ready to be used.

Theme is just set of files - it doesn't have content in database.

And about merging 2 databases...hmm...don't think that there is really good way to do that. There is some node export module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export

but it's a question how reliable it really is.